# Google Drive API returns 401 when attempting to authenticate

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

This is a brand-new project and my first attempts at using Google Drive's API. I get an immediate 401 when I run:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var filestream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(filestream).Secrets,
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("DriveCommandLineSample")).Result;
        }
```

This code is copied verbatim from https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs. I downloaded the JSON file as *client_secrets.json* and verified that GoogleClientSecrets.Load(filestream).Secrets holds the same values as the ones I see on the Credentials page.

I've tested with Firefox and IE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by selecting my email address in the the ***Email address*** drop-down on the ***Consent screen*** page. (It was previously unset.)

I created another Google Project and left the email address blank. It exhibited the same behavior until I set the email address.

Answer (score 0):

@saltface i can t comment so i post here.

Which API do you want to use? Drive API or Drive SDK?

`401 error` means that you have not identified, your credentials are wrong or maybe you have not enable the API from [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Have you enable the api? And then if it is the case... have you generated the web key?.

You can see that from [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

There you have to go to the left menu APIs/Auth => APIs .

There you need to search for the 'Drive' and enable the API. Once you have done that you will need to create a Credential.

Comment: I'm using Drive API. I already had to do all those things to generate the JSON file.

Comment: Ok, and that code you are running is a web app, no?
Because you need to create a key for browsers and another one is for android apps. Are you using the right one?

Comment: Yes. I selected _installed application_ and _other_. My credentials are under the heading _Client ID for native application_.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this question has been answered, but just as a note to others:*

Recently, I was getting a `401 Unauthorized` error response when attempting to set up Google Drive "push notifications" (webhooks). As it turns out, it was because my access token had expired! You can re-generate a valid token by running the code sample [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample).